# Shaliach Tzibur (Chazzan) who mumbles the words

Tags: halacha, rebuke-tochacha, embarrassment

What is the correct thing to do if you are in a minyan and the Shaliach Tzibur mumbles all the words together? I am talking about in the middle of davening and not afterwards which I think every Rav would agree that he should be spoken to (softly and with respect etc.), and the Gabbai informed him so he won't become Shaliach Tzibur again. My question is specifically when he is in the middle of Kedusha or Chazarat HaShatz. On the one hand, you have the needs of the Tzibor and Kavod Shaim but on the other hand, you will Embarrass another Yid (and yourself) by yelling out "enunciate your words!"

Comment: Is it viable to go up to him and tell him quietly enough that no one else or at least few other people can hear?  Not saying this is the right thing to do, but just to clarify the question

Comment: I was thinking about that, but then there would be an awkward pause, and everyone would look up at the Shaliach Tzibur, which would be even more embarrassing for the Shaliach Tzibur (but less embarrassing for the person giving tochacha). Also, by yelling out "enunciate your words!" you have the added benefit that everyone who is part of the minyan will be more careful when davening.

Comment: MB says if he can't enunciate properly not to appoint him in the first place. 
 https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.53.37?lang=bi&with=all

Comment: @Shababnik 100% he shouldn't be appointed, but I am asking about after he was appointed or just decided to go up himself and is in middle

Comment: I have no source for this; but I would say to not embarrass this person publicly. Which I would say supercedes the obligation of the chazara. Though what do I know. I await someone's response